# Replacing string while preserving some content

Tags: php, regex, wildcard, bbcode

So I am trying to figure out how I can an input such as

```
[url=value]
```

and turn it into

```
<a href="value">
```

Of course, I want to preserve that value. Thanks for the help!

Ultimately I want to be able to feed in any target and replacement, including `[email=value]` to `<a href="mailto:value">`.

So far I have:

```
$before = explode($fix['before'],"value");
$after = explode($fix['after'],"value");
preg_replace('/\\'.$before[0].'(.+?)'.'\\'.$before[1].'/', $after[0].'\1'.$after[1], $post);
```

Comment: Please research this yourself. SO isn't a place to ask "How to .." questions but rather "Why .." ;)

Comment: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: $fix in /your/question on line 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions. In PHP, you can use the [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function. An example regex you could use for that would be `/\[url=(.+)\]/` and the replacement would be `<a href="$1">`

Comment: You'll need to define that `.+` as group `(.+)` or the reference `$1` won't work

Comment: Yeah I have gotten that far. What I want to ultimately be able to do though is use a variable containing `[url=value]` or `[email=value]` etc and feed it into the script and have it process.

So far I have

`$before = explode($fix['before'],"value");
$after = explode($fix['after'],"value");
   preg_replace('/\\'.$before[0].'(.+?)'.'\\'.$before[1].'/', $after[0].'\1'.$after[1], $post);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
\[(.*?)=([^\]]+)]
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/nL6lH9

Test string:

```
[url=http://www.web.com/test.php?key=valuepair]
```

Matches:

```
match[1]: "url"
match[2]: "http://www.web.com/test.php?key=valuepair"
```

PHP:

```
$teststring = '[url=http://www.web.com/test.php?key=valuepair]';

preg_match('/\[(.*?)=([^\]]+)]/', $teststring, $match);

// So you could test if $match[1] == 'url' or 'email' or etc.

switch ($match[1]) {
    case "url":
        $output = '<a href="'.$match[2].'">Link</a>';
        break;
    case "email":
        $output = '<a href="mailto:'.$match[2].'">Send Email</a>';
        break;
}
echo str_replace($teststring, $output, $teststring);
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://www.web.com/test.php?key=valuepair">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll see how far I can get from this!